# Is it slower to use String.valueOf(myString)?

Tags: java, string

This is just an informational question, I don't need you to tell me that I shouldn't use it.

My question is : if I use `string1 = String.valueOf(string2);` , is it slower than `string1 = string2;` ?

The thing is : I would like to use a method to get a String from integers, doubles ect... and strings. I just would like to know if I should create another method.

Thanks, and sorry if this is a dupplicate, I didn't find it

Comment: Yes, unless the compiler inlines the call, you have some overhead. The question is, does it matter?

Comment: It's easy to find [the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.toString%28%29). It's slower as it calls two methods but those methods don't do anything heavy. In fact they only do a few tests to return the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, yes. It is slower by invoking two method calls both of which do no work (`valueOf()` and `toString()` on the String object).

Practically, not at all, unless you're doing it millions of times (and nothing else to it). Invoking two almost no-op methods doesn't cost you anything.

Comment: Thanks! Basically, I need my Android App to be very fast, but some millis won't slow it too much I guess

Answer (score 4):

Oh, probably *slightly* slower since `String.valueOf(object o)` is effectively `o.toString()` if `o` is not `null`. So, you have the overhead of method calls that could or could not be inlined. **The effect is however extremely small**. But that is *not* what matters here, what matters is *clarity*.

```
string1 = string2
```

more clearly expresses your intent than

```
string1 = String.valueOf(string2);
```

Therefore, for this reason, use the former. This is a no brainer.

You didn't say if it's the case or not, but I feel comfortable assuming that you meant to tell us that `string1` and `string2` are `String`s.

Answer (score 1):

It is slower, from the simple fact that you are making a method call as opposed to simple memory location assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and your explanation don't match up.

`String s1 = s2` is faster than `String s1 = String.valueOf(s2)` (for the proof: try it yourself, it's just a timed for loop with randomised strings).

However, your explanation is that you want to get Strings from numbers, which simply uses `String s = ""+<thing>` (thing can be a primitive, like `int` or `double`, but also any Object, in which case its `toString()` is implicitly called), so which of the two are you asking about?

Finally, your question is about speed: none of these different approaches will matter to any significant degree to the runtime speed of your program, even if you're parsing millions of entries. The slowdown between the two will make a difference of seconds on several hours of runtime. This is not worth optimizing.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! In fact, I didn't know the way `String s = ""+<thing>`. In fact, I have some values which navigate between files, classes, service ect... I finally write them in a new file, but for good reasons, I have to sometimes convert them to Strings. I would like to be able to do it with only one method (which does other things too). My values can be Strings like they can be integers

Answer (score 0):

The classes `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, `Boolean` all have a method `valueOf(String s)`. This converts a `String` to the desired class. You don't need additional classes.

Answer (score 0):

Of course String.valueOf(string2) is slower, this is a method call with dozens of bytecode operations while assigning a value to a local var is a couple of bytecodes.

As for integers, doubles etc we have no other choice but to call String.valueOf

Comment: Small correction there: `String s = "" + <thing>` is a terse, universal way to convert anything to a string by letting the compiler figure out which substitution to use.